# Spring Message Driven Channel Adapter along with JMS outbound Gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have a **jms:message-driven-channel-adapter** and in its downstream I have a **jms:outbound-gateway**.
The problem occurs whenever I get message in channel adapter in one thread like below

[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer**#1-4**] and gateway response in another therad like below:

[org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer**#3-5**].

I get a weird exception:

org.springframework.integration.MessageRejectedException: Message was rejected due to XML Validation errors; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.xml.AggregatedXmlMessageValidationException: Multiple causes:
    cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'NS1:FindPermitsByPersonNoRes'.

But whenever both thread ids are identical, I do not get any exception.

Below is my config of gateway:

```
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="jms_replyTo" ref="outboundQueue" overwrite="true"/>
        <int:header name="jms_type" type="java.lang.String" value="1" overwrite="true" />
        <int:header name="jms_correlationId" type="java.lang.String" expression="T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()" overwrite="true" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <jms:outbound-gateway 
        request-channel="gateway_request_channel"
        request-destination="inboundQueue"
        reply-destination="outboundQueue" 
        correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
        connection-factory="brokerConnectionFactory">

        <jms:reply-listener/>

    </jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `<reply-listener/>`, the reply is always delivered to the gateway on a separate thread (owned by the reply listener container); it's handed over to the first thread that is waiting for the reply inside the gateway. So something else is going on; you need to show full stack traces and configuration.

You don't need to set `replyTo` and `correlationId` headers; the gateway will take care of all that.

Comment: As you said there was some misconfiguration that was causing this issue. The correlationId I am specifying because of following reason.

Note: when using a <reply-container/> the correlation 
 data includes a UUID representing the gateway as well as a message identifier. For this reason, the use of a 
 <reply-container/> requires the specification of a 'correlation-key' if an explicit reply-destination is 
 provided."

Comment: Yes a `correlation-key` is needed to be specified on the gateway to tell it where to store it, but the gateway takes care of setting the value up (and the `replyTo`).

Comment: Whenever I am specifying JMSCorrelationID as correlation-key, debug log shows JMSCorrelationID value set to null, after message conversion to JMS message. The behavior is same even if I explicitly specify jms_correlationId header. Whereas, if I do not specify any value it gets default set to messageId. I am confused which option to use with <jms:reply-listener/> to ensure message goes back to right consumer thread.

Comment: As I said, set `correlation-key` to `JMSCorrelationID` to have the gateway automatically use internal gateway correlation so it can handle an async reply. Yes, it's null after conversion; it is inserted after conversion but before sending. See `JmsOutboundGateway.doSendAndReceiveAsync()`. If the `correlation-key` is null, the messageId is used for correlation. In either case you don't need to mess with the `jms_*` headers.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and for the clarification.